# Conflicted use of the learning tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

When looking at the [learning tag](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), three questions are regarding the learning of biology as a science whereas one is using learning in the ethology sense.  Clearly these two should be split up but which tag should take preference - self learning the field of biology or learning in a biological sense?

Answer (score 4):

Using [learning](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) for questions about resources for learning is pretty much using it as a meta tag. That is discouraged on all SE sites. There is not much use for such a tag, it is far better to tag those questions with the specific topic they are about, e.g. [cell-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-biology).

I removed all those instances of the tag and replaced them with something more useful.

Comment: Instead of [tag:learning] we should encourange the use of [tag:homework] in the questions tagetting the basic concepts of biology.

Comment: @Alexander I would interpret [tag:homework] as denoting something quite different. I agree with MadSci that having a tag that means "I want to learn" is pointless.

Comment: @AlexanderGalkin At math.SE, [tag:homework] means that the asker is looking for hints and help rather than a straight solution.